# How to add multiple filters in django query set

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a query set

`queryset = Record.objects.filter(type__icontains='28').exclude..............`

I want to add some other types also to my filter like `type__icontains='28' , type__icontains='14', type__icontains='20'` etc.

How can I do that? Please help

Comment: And or Or? If Or, you're probably looking for a Q object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q

Answer (score 4):

You have two options you will need to decide which one you use as your question is not very complete.

**IN syntax**

This is basically stating `select values where <attribute> IN <set>`

```
result = SomeModel.objects.filter(id__in=[28,14,20])

# same as
SELECT * FROM SomeModel WHERE SomeModel.id IN (28,14,20)
```

**Q Objects**

You will need to use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) objects. They allow for complex data queries. The good news is once you have read the [`django docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) (its really complete) you should be able to implement them easily into your code.

In your question you have not stated if you are trying to do an `AND` or `OR`. Just as a starting point you can do the following:

```
# AND
Q(type_icontains=28) & Q(type_icontains=14)

# OR
Q(type_icontains=28) | Q(type_icontains=14)
```